# Degree elevation of weighted Bezier curve to an arbitrary degree

Tags: bezier-curve

Following on from a [past question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509466/degree-elevation-of-weighted-bezier-curve) about degree elevation of a rational Bezier curve, of degree $n$ by one to $n + 1$, I am now looking to derive a *single* expression for degree elevation by an arbitrary number, say $m$, to $n + m$.

I'd appreciate help or insight into this problem or references, if this problem has already been addressed by someone. (I haven't been able to find any references.)

Comment: My I ask why you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For specific numerical values of $m$ and $n$, you can get what you want just by combining the formulae for one-step degree elevation, of course. You could make a large table of coefficients for all the degrees that interest you. A computer algebra system would be a big help in doing this.

If you want a symbolic formula in terms of general $m$ and $n$, I think it will be a huge incomprehensible mess. That's probably why it hasn't been derived in the past (as far as I know).